# drawRect() not working when partially off screen Android

Tags: android, canvas

The app I am building draws multiple objects on the screen at the same time. When one of the Squares it draws, using drawRect(), is partially off the screen it disappears.

I add it to the canvas with the following code

```
for(SquareObject s : squares) {
   canvas.drawRect(s.getLeft(), s.getTop(), s.getRight(), s.getBottom(), paint);
}
```

This code works fine in all instances, except when it goes off screen.

Does anyone know of a setting or something I am missing? Just doesn't seem to make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: it should work just fine,  i don't see any problems with that code

Comment: I know. Would it break with negative or larger then canvas size coordinates provided for one of the arguments?

Comment: no you can use any coordinates you want

Comment: What happens if you draw a rectangle using number you add manually and not letting the code fetch them from the variable. Put your own variables in and draw a rectangle that's stretching outside the canvas and see if it stays. The purpose is to determine if there's a problem with how the variables are fetched.

Comment: We face the same issue. Funny thing is, that rectangles that stretch outside of the canvas are correctly displayed on Nexus 5 (5.1.1 stock), but are not rendered on Samsung Galaxy S2 (5.1 Cyanogen).